# How to Set a Factory Function to Implement the Parameter Call Signature of the Class it Generates in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, decorator, aurelia

I am not even sure if what I want to do is possible. I am using a framework that provides decorators for dependency injection and it is very messy to properly type the code example below:

```js
class Control {
  constructor(
    options: {
      tabIndex?: number
    },
    callbacks: {
      onChange?: (event: any) => void,
    }
  ) {
  
  }
}

@inject(Factory.of(Control))
class Form {
  public GetControl: any;
  public control: Control;
  
  constructor(GetControl: any) {
    this.GetControl = GetControl;
  }
  build() {
    this.control = this.GetControl({tabIndex: 0}, null);
  }
}
```

Is there a way that I can set the type of `GetControl` without having to duplicate the parameter definitions in the Control Class like this:

```js
public GetControl: (
    options: {
      tabIndex?: number
    },
    callbacks: {
      onChange?: (event: any) => void,
    }
  ) => Control;
```

Comment: I do not really understand your questionyou want to set the return type of `GetControl` to `Control`?

Comment: No, that I know how to do. `GetControl` also takes in the same function parameters as `Control.constructor` and I was hoping I could derive the type definition for `GetControl` from `Control`. If I use `public GetControl: <Control>()=>{}` it will compile but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of TypeScript 2.8, we can get the type of `GetControl` from the class using tuples in rest parameters (read [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897)) and conditional types ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)).

```
class Control {
  constructor(
    options: {
      tabIndex?: number
    },
    callbacks: {
      onChange?: (event: any) => void,
    }
  ) {

  }
}

// Create a function with the same return type and parameters as a constructor
type Factory<T extends new (...a: any[]) => any> =
  T extends new (...a: infer A) => infer R ? (...a: A) => R : never;

class Form {
  ;
  public control: Control;
  // Shorthand field definition, same as your code but shorter :)
  constructor(public GetControl: Factory<typeof Control>) {
  }
  build() {
    this.control = this.GetControl({ tabIndex: 0 }, null);
  }
}
```

The type `Factory` transforms a constructor to a function with the same arguments. The way we do this is using the inference behavior of conditional types. If `T` extends a constructor type (which it does because of the type constraint) we ask the compiler to put in `A` a tuple containing the types of all parameters (`...a: infer A`) and in `R` the return type of the constructor ( `=> infer R`, this will be the class instance type).

Using `A` and `R` we can define the wanted function, with the return type `R` and we spread the arguments of the constructor to the arguments of the function (`(...a: A) => R`)

Comment: Perfect!!! This is what I was looking for. Any chance you could explain how the conditional/infer part works in more detail?

Comment: @KennethMoore I'll add a short explanation , the full explanation is in the links I reference.

Comment: @KennethMoore added an explanation, let me know if it makes sense :)

Comment: the explanation makes sense and it is helpful. Thanks for this solution.